# Fetching elevation of one point from MapQuest API in Leaflet

Tags: mapquest, elevation

I am trying to get elevation of clicked location via fetching elevation values from MapQuest elevation profile API

https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/open/elevation-api/elevation-profile/get/

But I can't find the parameter of getting elevation of only one point not for a route; I mean latLng not latLngCollection.

Here is my code:

```
var myLocation = e.latlng;
  console.log(myLocation);
  fetch('http://open.mapquestapi.com/elevation/v1/profile?key=tHXSNAGXRx6LAoBNdgjjLycOhGqJalg7&shapeFormat=raw&latLngCollection='+myLocation)
  .then(r => r.json()) 
    .then(data => {
      var elevation = data;
      console.log(data);
})
```

Is there is any way to get elevation for only one point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one location collection seems to be working as expected.

http://open.mapquestapi.com/elevation/v1/profile?shapeFormat=raw&key=KEY&latLngCollection=51.50631,%20-0.12714

Comment: In this request you have entered coordinates, but i need to enter parameter of coordinates via clicking, so how can i enter myLocation variable into the request?

Comment: Here is a very short version of how I put the lat/lng into an input box that ends up getting put into the request.

function mapclicked(e) {
 var ll = e.latlng.wrap();
 $("#origin").val(ll.lat.toFixed(5) + "," + ll.lng.toFixed(5));
}